# How can I build a state space model if I got two different second derivative in the same equation?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, control-theory, optimal-control, euler-lagrange-equation, linear-control

This is my inverted pendulum

[image]

And here is the all equations:

Potential energy: 
$$V = \frac{g l_{1}}{2} m_{1} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} + g l_{2} m_{2} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )}$$

Kinetic energy: 
$$T = \frac{M}{2} \left(\frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + \frac{l_{1}^{2} m_{1}}{2} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \left(\frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + \frac{l_{2}^{2} m_{2}}{2} \sin^{2}{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \left(\frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + \frac{m_{1}}{2} \left(l_{1} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )} + \frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + \frac{m_{2}}{2} \left(l_{2} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )} + \frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2}$$

And the langarian difference:

$$L = \frac{M}{2} \left(\frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} - \frac{g l_{1}}{2} m_{1} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} - g l_{1} m_{2} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} + \frac{l_{1}^{2} m_{1}}{2} \left(\frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + l_{1} m_{1} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )} \frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )} + \frac{l_{2}^{2} m_{2}}{2} \left(\frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + l_{2} m_{2} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )} \frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )} + \frac{m_{1}}{2} \left(\frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + \frac{m_{2}}{2} \left(\frac{d}{d t} x{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2}$$

And now the langarian equation:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_1}}) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial {q_1}} = Q_i$$

And that will be:

$$M \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} - l_{1} m_{1} \sin{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right)} \left(\frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + l_{1} m_{1} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} - l_{2} m_{2} \sin{\left (\theta{\left(t \right )} \right )} \left(\frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} + l_{2} m_{2} \cos{\left(\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} + m_{1} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} + m_{2} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} = F - Kx - B\dot{x}$$

$$- \frac{g l_{1}}{2} m_{1} \sin{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} - g l_{2} m_{2} \sin{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} + l_{1}^{2} m_{1} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} + l_{1} m_{1} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t \right )} \right )} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} + l_{2}^{2} m_{2} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} + l_{2} m_{2} \cos{\left (\theta{\left (t\right )} \right )} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} = -k \theta - b \dot{\theta}$$

Because the force inputs: 
$$Q_i = \begin{bmatrix}
F - Kx - B\dot{x}\\ 
-k \theta - b \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Octave code:

```
pkg load symbolic

% Symbols
syms m2 g l1 theta(t) m1 l2 M x(t) 

% Potential energy
V = m2*g*l2*cos(theta) + m1*g*l1*1/2*cos(theta);

% Kinect energy
T = 1/2*M*diff(x)^2 + 1/2*m2*(diff(x) + l2*diff(theta)*cos(theta))^2 + 1/2*m2*( - l2*diff(theta)*sin(theta))^2 + 1/2*m1*(diff(x)+l1*diff(theta)*cos(theta))^2 + 1/2*m1*( - l1*diff(theta)*sin(theta))^2;

% Difference
L =  simplify(T - V);

% Lagrange equation
dL = simplify(jacobian(L, [x theta]));
ddL =  simplify(diff(jacobian(L, [diff(x) diff(theta)])));

% Difference
A =  simplify(ddL - dL);

% Show each row
simplify(A(1))
simplify(A(2))

% Linearize sin theta(t) = theta, cos theta(t) = 1

B = simplify(subs(A, [sin(theta(t)) cos(theta(t)) diff(theta, 1)^2], [theta(t) 1 0]));

B(1) 
B(2)
```

And if I want to linearize those equation when the rod is pointing straight up, I can just say that 
$$sin (\theta) = \theta \\ cos (\theta) = 1 \\ \left(\frac{d}{d t} \theta{\left (t \right )}\right)^{2} = 0, \text{then} \space sin (\theta) = 0$$

And now the equations are linear.

$$M \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} + l_{1} m_{1} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} + l_{2} m_{2} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} + m_{1} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} +m_{2} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} = F - Kx - B\dot{x}$$

$$- \frac{g l_{1}}{2} m_{1} \theta{\left (t \right )} - g l_{2} m_{2} \theta{\left (t \right )} + l_{1}^{2} m_{1} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} + l_{1} m_{1} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} + l_{2}^{2} m_{2} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  \theta{\left (t \right )} + l_{2} m_{2} \frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}  x{\left (t \right )} = -k \theta - b \dot{\theta}$$
**Question:**

How can I build a state space model if I got two different second derivative in the same equation? In this case it's $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{\theta}$

**Edit:**

Thanks Kwin! 
[image]

**Edit2:**

It works now. Here is a test

```
M = 10;
m1 = 2;
m2 = 5;
l1 = 5;
l2 = 5.4;
K = 3;
B = 2;
g = 9.82;
k = 4;
b = 2;

M = [(M+m1+m2) (l1*m1 + m2*l2); (l1*m1 + m2*l2) (l1^2*m1 +l2^2*m2)];
A = [-K -B 0 0; 0 0 (1/2*g*l1*m1 + g*l2*m2 -k) -b ];

Omega = inv(M)*E;

A = [0 1 0 0; Omega(1,1) Omega(1,2) Omega(1,3) Omega(1,4); 0 0 0 1; Omega(2,1) Omega(2,2) Omega(2,3) Omega(2,4)];

B = [0; 1; 0; 0];

sys = ss(0, A, B);

pole(sys)
ans =

  -1.65310 + 0.00000i
  -0.06384 + 0.42388i
  -0.06384 - 0.42388i
   1.56360 + 0.00000i

Q = eye(4);
R = 1;
L = lqr(sys, Q, R);

regsys = reg(sys, L);

pole(regsys)
ans =

  -0.84316 + 0.59903i
  -0.84316 - 0.59903i
  -1.65264 + 0.00000i
  -1.54574 + 0.00000i
```

Remember that the positive eigenvalue from pole(sys) is probably the rotation $\theta$ of the cart. Giving the pendulum a negative feedback, then the feedback model would have all negative eigenvalues, which means stable system.

Comment: Maybe vectorise all variables and their time derivatives?

Comment: @mathreadler you mean creating states?

Comment: I am not used to all the control lingo. So I am not sure that is what I mean.

Comment: @mathreadler creating states is saying that $$r_1 = x, r_2 = \dot{x}, r_3 = \theta, r_4 = \dot{\theta}$$ Then we can write my system at the first order and put all the derivatives on the left side of the equation. But still! I get two types of derivatives.

Comment: Maybe you can relate them to each other? What is the relation between $x$ and $\theta$? And what is $y$ exactly, it does not seem to point anywhere specific.

Comment: @mathreadler $y$ is just the height and does not mean anything in this case. $x$ can be very large and still $\theta$ can be zero. So they have no relation. But if I try do linearize the equations by saying $sin \theta = 0$ and $cos \theta = 1$ and I will come back later.

Comment: Their derivatives and second derivatives could still be related. Just imagine removing all outside forces and dropping everything letting gravity do it's work. Surely the pendulum beginning to accelerate in some trajectory towards the ground would push the wagon sideways (because otherwise the momentum laws in x-direction would be violated)?

Comment: @mathreadler Wait a few seconds. I will add more information in the question :)

Comment: @mathreadler I have now linearized the equations so it's much clear and linear.

Comment: I was quite sure the control wishful thinking guys didn't get what I meant with linearize. And the dudes name is Lagrange and Lagrangian with a big L.

Comment: @mathreadler Sorry!

Comment: In most text books it is the convention to add the affects of springs in a system to the potential energy of the system as well and not to the external forces ($Q$ is then also often called the nonconservative forces). However the end result for the differential equation will be the same.

Comment: So it's OK for me to add external forces at $Q$ matrix? I just wanted some input forces to control the system. I edited your answer.

Comment: I moved the picture to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a differential equation of the second order

$$
\ddot{x} = f(t, x, \dot{x})
$$

then you can always write it as first order differential equation as well by defining a new state vector as $z = \begin{bmatrix}x^\top & \dot{x}^\top\end{bmatrix}^\top$ such that

$$
\dot{z} = \begin{bmatrix}\dot{x} \\ f(t,x,\dot{x})\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

In your case your differential equation can be written as

$$
\mathbf{M} \begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{x} \\ \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix} = f(t, x, \theta, \dot{x}, \dot{\theta})
$$

with

$$
\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
M + m_1 + m_2 & l_1\,m_1 + l_2\,m_2 \\
l_1\,m_1 + l_2\,m_2 & l_1^2\,m_1 + l_2^2\,m_2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Assuming that $\mathbf{M}$ is invertible, then your differential equation can also be written as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{x} \\ \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{M}^{-1}\,f(t, x, \theta, \dot{x}, \dot{\theta})
$$

which is of the same form as at the start of this answer, only now you have to define the new state space as $z = \begin{bmatrix}x & \theta & \dot{x} & \dot{\theta}\end{bmatrix}^\top$.

Comment: Yes! I know how to defining a new state vector, but how do I need to do when I have $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{\theta}$ in the same equation? I want to put all the derivatives of first order to the left, as a normal state space representation should be.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I have updated my answer to cover this.

Comment: So I don't need to write the system on first order, I can write it at second order?

Comment: Perfect! I think it works! I haven't try the model yet, but I want to upload it here as a PDF-file.

Comment: But the $M$ matrix is not going to be square?

Comment: I have uploaded a picture. Have a look at it and see if it's correct or not?

Comment: Hi. The matrix $M$ was not invertible. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson The $\mathbf{M}$ matrix should be 2 by 2 not 4 by 4. First solve for an explicit expression for $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{\theta}$ using the inverse of the 2 by 2 $\mathbf{M}$ matrix, and after that extend the state space.

Comment: Ok! I till do that! I will give you a reply.

Comment: Now I have done it. Se my question. There is a picture there.

Comment: I did check the eigenvalues, it did not gave a stable result.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Did you expect it to be stable (you are dealing with an inverted pendulum)?

Comment: No. But I at least expecting that I have all negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Maybe I have done some errors in my calculations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74713/discussion-between-kwin-van-der-veen-and-daniel-martensson).