# Differential equation with more than one 2nd order differentiation term and they have time dependent coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

If there are two 2nd order differential terms in the equations than getting the state-space formulation is not very difficult. That I have seen here for the 2nd order terms [with two different variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697394/how-can-i-build-a-state-space-model-if-i-got-two-different-second-derivative-in/2697575#comment5569995_2697575). But I am facing a typical problem. Another second-order differential term is a function of the first term and it has time-dependent coefficients.

Here I am mentioning the system of equations.
$$\ddot{Y} + [A] Y + B \ddot{y_b} + C y_b = f(t)$$
$Y=[y_1   y_2  ..... y_n ]^T$ is a column vector of variables. Here $A$ is a coefficient matrix and $B, C$ are coefficient vectors with known values and $y_b$ is a scaller variable. It is given as, $y_b = G (y_n + \alpha y_n^3)cos(\Omega t)$
After substituting expression of $y_b$, the equation will have more than one 2nd order derivative term and they will have time dependent coefficients.

In such cases, transformation to state space is not possible, because of $Cos(\Omega t)$ is multiplied to the $\ddot {Y}$ terms. In addition to it becomes typically nonlinear also.

I have used Matlab function `odeToVectorField`(which does the state-space conversion automatically) and `matlabFunction` and then solved it using `ode45`. But, now I want to apply Runge Kutta 4th order or some other method, which can do faster simulation. Can someone help me to deal with this problem?

Comment: Why do you think that fixed-step RK4 will be faster (at the same accuracy level) than 4th order adaptive step-size ode45? You will usually find that ode45 takes less steps to reach the same accuracy. Get the full output with the info structure, compare the count of function evaluations.

Comment: What prevents you from taking the same function you obtained from `matlabFunction` and using it in the RK4 implementation, for instance from [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54611-solving-odes-in-matlab#functions_tab)

Comment: Surprisingly I found that if the number of elements in variable vector "Y"  is large than RK4 is faster. I will try the output from `matlabFunction` into RK4. It can work nicely, Thank you.

Comment: But still is some method is there to deal with this problem via using some other numerical method, like Newmark method is usually applied in FEM for such equations, but I can't apply it directly here. Acceleration term has time-dependent coefficients.

Comment: If this comes from a model and is unexpected, it might also be that the model or its translation into equations is wrong. Else in this case you can treat the last equation separately, $\ddot y_n$ occurs only linearly and thus it can be solved for it and then inserted in the other equations.

Comment: Modelling and the equations are correct. They are for a structure which is discretized into $n$ parts. Detailed description is difficult here. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by treating or solving $\ddot{y_n}$ separately. Actually all the $n$ equations are coupled by the matrices and vectors.

Comment: Yes, they are coupled, but the leading-order term in the last equation is $[1+B_nG(1+3αy_n(t)^2)\cos(Ωt)]\ddot y_n(t)$, so as long as the first factor is not zero you can isolate $\ddot y_n$ from that equation. When you get a zero of that factor, your solution ends, this singularity bounds the maximal domain.

Comment: Yes Yes, but $\ddot{y_n}$ terms are there added in all the n equations. Are you talking about using the last equation and calculating $y_n$ from $y_i$ values of previous iterations and then using it.

 I can combine all the second order term by using a row vector $[0 0.... 1]* Y$ and can get a single $\ddot{Y}$ term for linear case at least $\alpha=0$. But further proceeding will be obviously very slow.

Can you suggest some other numerical method where state space transformation is not required.

Comment: No, no previous state. You get an input of state and velocity, and from that you can compute all the accelerations. Once you have $\ddot y_n$ you can insert that value in all the other equations to compute the remaining $\ddot y_k$, $k<n$. Can't you display the content of the `matlabFunction` generated function?

Comment: It is difficult to paste here even for small number of  $n$. But the way you told can be applied. I will try that. Thanks. I was thinking to do this using newmark method where output of previous iterations can be feded to calculate $\ddot{y_n}$ and it can be used in other equations.